# Update Key value of Provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a page that goes after the main page which has its own `ChangeNotifierProvider`. The key given in the `main` method of the first page is a **static** String stored in the `ChangeNotifierProvider` class that I use in the second page.

When I update this `String` key before Navigator.pop() into the first page, coming back to the second page still has the same old values.

I heard changing the key lets you refresh the Provider stored values, so how do I do it? Or else how can I make sure everything is reset once I click a certain button to go back?

Answer (score 0):

I had thought that there was such a function like this in Provider but no, would've been useful.

For now my solution was to create constructor methods that set everything back, so I can call them before I navigate.